# Facebook API feed not showing caption/messege

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook feed, built on Facebook API. It works pretty well. But I have one problem. It seems like I can't catch some text from some status messeges.

Below you can see the API feed.

[image: This is how the API-feed looks like]

The two "empty" posts are these on Facebook:

[image: On facebook]

This is the call to get json (Token removed):

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/216896781666302/?access_token=*******&locale=sv_SE&date_format=U&fields=posts.limit(2){caption,message,picture,from,link,source,properties,icon,actions,is_hidden,is_expired,likes,comments,shares,status_type,object_id,created_time,updated_time,type}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/216896781666302/?access_token=*******&locale=sv_SE&date_format=U&fields=posts.limit(2)%7Bcaption,message,picture,from,link,source,properties,icon,actions,is_hidden,is_expired,likes,comments,shares,status_type,object_id,created_time,updated_time,type%7D)

The problem: I do not get the following texts: "Kultur Karlshamn har uppdaterat sin adress." and "Kultur Karlshamn har uppdaterat informationen i avsnittet Om". And I can not find any clear answer on this problem. Why do I not get the header/texts? What field am I missing in my API/json-call?

This is the  data I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of those posts that are created automatically can be found in the `story` field.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/post:

> **story**: Text from stories not intentionally generated by users, such as those generated when two people become friends, or when someone else posts on the person's wall.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Tested, but still getting the same data as in json screenshot above. (Not getting story field from these posts).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=216896781666302%2F%3Ffields%3Dposts%257Bstory%257D%26locale%3Dsv_SE&version=v2.10

Comment: Sorry, but not getting story when I add the other values I need: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=216896781666302%2F%3Ffields%3Dposts.limit(2)%7Bstory%2Ccaption%2Cmessage%2Cpicture%2Cfrom%2Clink%2Csource%2Cproperties%2Cicon%2Cactions%2Cis_hidden%2Cis_expired%2Clikes%2Ccomments%2Cshares%2Cstatus_type%2Cobject_id%2Ccreated_time%2Cupdated_time%2Ctype%7D%26locale%3Dsv_SE&version=v2.10

Comment: Not sure if all of those posts are available via API. When I go through them (without limit), I see some for stuff like cover photo changes, but not the two specific ones about updating the address or info ... Might be the same as with those birthday wishes-posts, those are not available via API either.

Comment: Don’t see anything in the details of a particular post, such as the one about the address change, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=216896781666302_1607231959299437%3Ffields%3Dcaption%2Cdescription%2Cchild_attachments%2Clink%2Cmessage%2Cmessage_tags%2Cname%2Cpermalink_url%2Cproperties%2Csource%2Cstatus_type%2Cstory%2Cstory_tags&version=v2.10

Comment: Maybe you should just suppress those posts in your output logic, where neither a message, caption, story, [...?] is set.